# D3 and AngularJS directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I'm trying to combine AngularJS and D3 -- two awesome libraries.  This example is contrived but I have a legitimate use case where I'd like to insert HTML with AngularJS directives by means of D3.

Here's an example with:

- a simple AngularJS directive,
- a simple adding of content with D3
- and finally adding a content with AngularJS directive using D3.

The last one does not work; why?

[Here's the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koper/4SGsc/).

#### HTML:

```
<body ng-app="d3">
    <div hello></div>
    <div hello-d3></div>
    <div hello-d3-angular></div>
</body>
```

#### JS:

```
angular.module('d3', [])
  .directive('hello', function() {
      return {
          template: 'Hello Angular!'
      };
  })
  .directive('helloD3', function() {
      return {
          link: function(scope,elt) {
              d3.select(elt[0]).append('div').text('Hello d3!')
          }
      };
  })
  .directive('helloD3Angular', function($compile) {
      return {
          link: function(scope,elt) {
              var node = $compile('<div hello></div>')(scope);
              d3.select(elt[0]).append(node[0]);
          }
      };
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's about D3 API, [`selection.append(name)`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-append) .

> The name may be specified either as a constant string or as a function that returns the DOM element to append.

http://jsfiddle.net/bateast/4SGsc/7/

So if you want to pass a DOM to `.append()`, try this instead:

```
d3.select(elt[0]).append(function() { return node[0]; });
```

Comment: Duh, I knew there's something simple that I'm missing... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using a callback arrow function

```
d3.select(elt[0]).append(function() {()=> $compile('<div hello></div>')(scope)[0] });
```